# How can I limit access to uploaded media depending on the logged in user's user role?

Tags: filters, media, user-access

I have a pretty straight-forward Wordpress site that uses a plugin called Subway to restrict access on the page only to logged in users. There's also the following .htaccess-rule:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]`

I can define access depending on user role very easily. However, it doesn't seem to work so well with Media attachments.

I am a bit new to Filters in Wordpress, but shouldn't there be a way to restrict access to a file based on a user's user role via functions.php?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't restrict direct access to a file uploaded on a single site to the standard uploads as it's served directly by the server using just PHP, not by WordPress, however, 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, if you want to use options set in Subway to do user control then you will need to contact their dev support

Comment: @TomJNowell I've managed to solve this using an own PHP-script, that uses Wordpress functions. Would it be on-topic to post the solution here (no plugin involved)?